# How can I get all images in a page using JSoup then download into ImageView using Picasso?

Tags: android, jsoup, picasso

I'm trying to parse a webpage's images and show them in a grid using Picasso. My grid works fine with dummy data and with the sample that Picasso provided. My code doesn't yield anything in my grid (not even the error message).

I want to parse this particular webpage's image links so that I don't have to manually add them to my project (the same way Picasso did for examples). Here is my code:

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

    Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sample.com/examples.html").get();
                Elements imgs = doc.select("img");
                //String img_url = imgs.attr("src");
                for (Element i : imgs) {
                    //added this line to check if my jsoup is correct
                    System.out.println(i.attr("abs:src"));
                    urls.add(i.attr("abs:src"));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    downloadThread.start();
}
```

This is my adapter's getView.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_grid_view, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitName);
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageViewTopCrop) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitImage);
        holder.thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageViewTopCrop.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // Set Text
    holder.title.setText(position);

    //set thumbnail URL
    String url = getItem(position);

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(mContext) //
            .load(url) //
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
            .error(R.drawable.error) //
            .tag(view) //
            .into(holder.thumbnail);
    return view;
```

Now, my logcat shows that my Jsoup is correct (it prints the correct links). However, my GridView still shows nothing.

Comment: Are you able to see the error image in the girdview because you have set the error image if the download image is not shown? ,Generally in Picasso A request will be retried three times before the error placeholder is shown.

Comment: Good call. Actually, nothing shows. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: :have you mentioned the internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ? and also check the placeholder image is shown or not?

Comment: I have internet permission. My grid works with the sample data I provided-  a list of urls added  right after mContext=context. Placeholder isn't shown.

Comment: Ok try checking the values of url , context, view  are not null ,i.e, make if condition to ensure that these variables are not null , if it is not null then invoke Picasso code , else print a log message

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: I got a Null Pointer from my ImageViewTopCrop object. I'm checking if I still get this error if I just use a normal ImageView.

Comment: This is the problem dude,try    holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitImage); instead of    holder.thumbnail = (ImageViewTopCrop) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitImage);

Comment: Hmm, the thing is, I want to center my image horizontally and fit the top part. Using a normal imageview just fits the image or crops from the center. 

Also, ImageViewTopCrop works for my sample data..

Comment: Strange. I didn't change anything and just kept running the app over and over and it worked.. once.. and crashed by the time I got to the last items in the gridview. Thoughts? I'm still trying to reproduce this "success"..

Comment: Could you please post your Crash Report?

Comment: I may have found the real culprit. My debugger says: the application may be doing too much work on its main thread.  However, I tried a page with less images and I still got the same message. Thoughts? I think I should use a different thread for loading the images but doesn't Picasso do that for me?